# How to read multiple blocks of strings from text file

Tags: c++, file, scanf

I'm brand new to C++, and am working on a quiz program that reads from multiple text files containing Questions that look like this, but the number of answers per question is different:

> {mc} When a C program starts, the function that gets executed is called ________
>
> - [ ] principal
> - [X] main
> - [ ] function
> - [ ] func
> - [ ] program

I assign the "{mc}"  to my question type, read the rest of the line to my Question variable, Then I read each line, excluding the "[]" and assign each string to in my answers array.

I'm thinking it would be like this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%4s %[^\n]%*c %*s %s ", questionType, question, answer, etc...)
```

I don't know how to account for the number of answers being different, the max num of answers is 10. How do I read all the answers and stop before the next question? Could I turn this into a function and read each file question by question? Can I turn this into a loop so I can capture the choices in a string array?

Comment: Read in a line from the file. If the first 4 characters on the line are {mc}, you found it. Easy as cake.

Comment: Yeah that's easy, my issue is I don't know how to read the choices into an array, and stop before accidentally reading the next question

Comment: Don't read choices into an array.  Read choices into `std::vector<string>`, using `std::getline`.

Comment: It wasn't specified that we need to use scanf, it's just what was used in the first part of 
If not scanf, would it be something like    
while (getline(file, line)) {
    if (line.find("{mc}") != string::npos) {
     questionType = "mc";

Comment: `if (line.find("{mc}") != string::npos)` would probably be better with `if (line.find("{mc}") == 0)` or `if (line.starts_with("{mc}"))` if your compiler's right up to date or something similar so the program doesn't get fooled by a line with a {mc} buried somewhere in the middle of a line.